# How to get many data from EditText using UI programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

Halo guys,

I'm making a class that displays the UI programmatically.
I want to display a lot of EditText based on feedback from users.

Here's the code

```
    public class UIThroughCode extends Activity {

            static int dx3;
            public static void setkriteria(String d2, String d3){
             dx2 = Integer.parseInt(d2);
             dx3 = Integer.parseInt(d3);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Params for views
        LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        // create a layout
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        //here my question, how to get data from EditText ?? 
        for (int i = 0; i <dx3; i++)
                {
            EditText et = new EditText(this);
            et.setLayoutParams(params);
            layout.addView(et);
        }

        // Create a Button
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("This is a Button");
        btn.setLayoutParams(params);

        // Add the button
        layout.addView(btn);

        // Create a layout param for the layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        this.addContentView(layout, layoutParam);
    }
}
```

I was get data string d2 and d3 from other class, and parsing them into Integer.
here my question, how to get data from all EditText ??

Thankyou very much:)

Comment: I don't know if this is your question, but  Integer.parseInteger(EditText.getText().toString)) might do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try this its just pseudo code I have not tested it

```
l=layout,getViews()
for(Object o:l){
 if(o instanceOf EditText){
  EditText e=(EditText)o;
  e.getText()

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getText()` method as specified in the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html).

If you have to get **ALL** of the texts from all your `EditText`s than you can store a reference to all your `EditText`s in a `List` like this:

```
List<EditText> = new ArrayList<EditText>();
```

and simply iterate over them or you can iterate over `LinearLayout`'s Children like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
  if(layout.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText) {
    String text = ((EditText)layout.getChildAt(i)).getText();
  }
}
```

Make sure you clear all of your unused references by the way because android tends to be leaky.